# SSH LocalForward a unix socket to a windows tcp port using .ssh/config

Tags: windows, ssh, port-forwarding

I have a development server running docker, and generally connect to it from Windows 10 like this:

```
> ssh -V
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.4

> ssh -NL localhost:23750:/var/run/docker.sock my-devserver
```

I have an `/.ssh/config` file that conveniently forwards some ports for me, for example postgres on 5432:

```
Host my-devserver
    IdentityFile C:\Users\MyUserName\.ssh\id_rsa
    HostName devserver.example.com
    User someuser
    LocalForward 5432 localhost:5432
```

What I would like to do is to set my `.ssh/config` to also forward `/var/run/docker.sock` from the remote server to port 23750. I naively tried:

```
    LocalForward /var/run/docker.sock localhost:23750
```

But this fails with:

```
bind: Not a socket
unix_listener: cannot bind to path: /var/run/docker.sock
```

Why is this failing, and how can I configure the host to forward the socket file to a tcp port under windows from `.ssh/config`?

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate of the other question. I am running under Windows, which doesn't support unix sockets, and I can forward the unix socket to a tcp port already from the command line. The question is how to get this to happen within ssh/config.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reverse the order of the parameters:

```
    LocalForward 23750 /var/run/docker.sock
```